# Remap Left Alt to act as AltGr and to act as regular Alt when pressing Fn+Left Alt

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macintosh

setxkbmap, xmodmap and xcape are driving me insane!

I'm using a macbook pro with **us layout** and **mac variant.** In macOS when you press and hold left or right alt keys they turn into a modifier so you can type accents. I want to reproduce the same behavior on linux. Right now this happens only with right alt key (altgr).

**First problem**: I can't figure out how to remap left alt key to act as AltGr. I tried researching, reading docs, and blind solutions but nothing.

**Second problem**: I must keep my right alt key (altgr) function intact. In essence what I need is two altgr keys.

**Third problem**: I don't want to lose regular Alt key completely so I must program another combination of keys for it to work. I was thinking in Fn+Alt_L = regular Alt.

I know the tools that will likely get the job done: setxkbmap or xmodmap and xcape. I've already done something similar with Caps Lock (Esc on single press and Control_L when holded) and with Tab (Tab on single press and Super_L when holded).

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what is the distinction you make between "press" and "hold"? I think modifiers such as Ctrl, Alt, etc. only make sense if they are hold and then other key is pressed, thus the name "modifiers".

Comment: I thought as in Firefox for example. When you press and release Alt_L it shows the menu containing "File, Edit, View, etc". It won't show the menu until you release Alt key. But now that I think about other apps I see this would be a problem since there would be no way of distinguish Alt from AltGr.

The ideal solution I guess would be making Alt_L act as Alt_Gr and Fn+Alt_L acting as the regular Alt key for example.

I'll edit my question for clarification , thank you!

Comment: Indeed, some programs use Alt alone. Well, I don't think there is a solution that does not involve having one Alt and another Alt-Gr key. Most likely Fn cannot be used because [the OS does not even detect it](https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key)...

Comment: If you really need two Alt_Gr keys, you could make your CapsLock a normal Alt, but maybe you don't like the idea of giving up your CapsLock, then you could relinquish one function key (F1-F12, they are usually pretty useless). There may be other better ways, but sorry, dealing with the keyboard is painfully difficult. If you are OK with any of these alternatives, I think I can help.

Comment: Thank you! It actually helped. I didn't know about Fn behavior. I've managed to get both Alt keys working as desired. I've discovered that for my specific layout/variant (US layout with Mac variant) AltGr key acts as 3rd level chooser key. By typing `$ setxkbmap -option lv3:alt_switch` both keys act as desired now. But in trade off I lost Alt key and I'm having some trouble for remapping it. I'd be okay with remapping it to F1-F12.